# Is there any way to get base type stored in a variable or member pointer?

Tags: c++, type-deduction

Consider the following code

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class A {};

class B : public A {};

class C : public A {};


void parseType(A* base)
{ 
   std::cout << typeid(std::remove_pointer<decltype(base)>::type).name() << "\n";
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A* a = new B;

    A* b = new C;

    parseType(a); // outputs A

    parseType(b); // outputs A

    return 0;
}
```

there's any way to get the type stored in `base` parameter from function `parseType()`? literally always the type it's the `base` type.

Comment: Logically i would like avoid using templates if it's possible...

Comment: Not in front of a computer now but... first, your classes are not polymorphic. Second, if you make them polymorphic and use typeid(base) without all the decltype stuff should work

Comment: @linuxfever obviously, but i was trying to deduct the type for use it... as i see, i guess is not possible...

Comment: Most of the time, asking your question indicates that a poor design choice has already been made, and it's time to back up and re-evaluate your earlier choices. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @JaMiT for override existing virtual methods from another class through a instance... i didn't want to fill my classes with useless methods...

Comment: @nikomaster: it would help us a lot if you could update your question to tell us what your end goal is. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Even if what you were asking was possible (which is not), what were you planning to do with it?

Comment: @nikomaster That explanation is very unclear to me. I think that to explain what you are trying to do, you need more space than is available in a comment. (I.e. update your question with the explanation. Make it detailed; pretend we have no clue about what you are trying to do, nor about what you have tried so far.)

Comment: @JaMiT is not need, already found a solution, but it was putting all my setters/getters on the base class... (personally i don't like it.), i was trying to do a composite pattern based... so my goal was like: `class Child : decltype(Base) { public: virtual void method() override { ... } };` i know i can use friend classes on base class, but i didn't want to break the pattern rule i readed out in a book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Just dereference the pointer and apply the `typeid`:

```
void parseType(A* base)
{ 
    std::cout << typeid(*base).name() << "\n";
}
```

The reason is that `typeid` will evaluate the operand at runtime if its operand is a *glvalue expression of polymorphic type*.  In your original example, `decltype` is a compile time operation and extracts the static type of `base`, so it's always `A`.

Note that this requires `A` to have at least one virtual member function so that it qualifies as a polymorphic type.  Also, you forgot to `#include <typeinfo>`.

Comment: I put the `typeid::name()` just for log, but i'm talking about of type it self...

Comment: @nikomaster Of course you can't get the runtime type at compile time ...  If then, you have to pass the original type.